# Problem 9 - Chapter 5 - Evans' PDE (First Edition) - Clarification

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, integral-inequality

I've been trying to work out the solution to Question 9 in Chapter 5 of Evans, and I'm having some difficulties.

I've been looking at the solution posted here: [Question $5.9$ - Evans PDE $2$nd edition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/369989/question-9-chap-5-evans-pde?rq=1)

And I can follow it through up to the Holder inequality step, but after that, I'm kind of lost with what I should be doing. The author of that solution says to divide by the gradient term, which I assume means the entire integral, but I'm not 100% sure what this will actually look like, especially when the integrals have exponents on them, and the terms inside each integral have differing exponents.

If anyone could provide a bit of insight into this step, it'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end we don't want the gradient term on the RHS of the inequality:
$$\int_U|Du|^p\,dx\le C\left(\int_U |u|^\frac{p}{2} |D^2u|^\frac{p}{2}\right)^\frac{2}{p} \left(\int_U |Du|^p \right)^\frac{p-2}{p},$$
dividing by $\left(\int_U |Du|^p \right)^\frac{p-2}{p}$, we obtain
$$\left(\int_U |Du|^p \right)^{\frac{2}{p}}\le C\left(\int_U |u|^\frac{p}{2} |D^2u|^\frac{p}{2}\right)^\frac{2}{p}\le C\left(\int_U|u|^p\right)^\frac{1}{p}\left(\int_U|D^2u|^p\right)^\frac{1}{p},$$
taking $p/2$-th power we get the result.

Comment: In moving from the middle to right inequality on the last line, are you using Holder's Inequality again, or just moving powers around??

Comment: Holder's, $\int_U |u|^\frac{p}{2} |D^2u|^\frac{p}{2}=\||u|^\frac{p}{2}|D^2u|^\frac{p}{2}\|_{L^1}\le \||u|^\frac{p}{2}\|_{L^2}\||D^2u|^\frac{p}{2}\|_{L^2}=\|u^p\|_{L^1}^\frac{1}{2}\| |D^2u|^p\|_{L^1}^\frac{1}{2}.$

Comment: Just wanted to make sure, thank you!! :)

Comment: No worries, happy to help :)